# Как добавить объект содержащийся в 1 и 2 массивах в 3, при условии что в 3 нет такого же объекта?

Tags: javascript, массивы, angularjs

Пишу SPA на angularJS. Есть 3 массива, первый и второй получают данные в виде объектов - http запрос к api instagram. В третий массив необходимо поместить одинаковые элементы из первого и второго.

```
$scope.dataStorage1 = [];
$scope.dataStorage2 = [];
$scope.commonDataStorage = [];
```

После http запроса к api 1 и 2 массивы содержат объекты, в каждом объекте есть свойство id по значению которого и выполняю сравнение.

```
function getCommonData() {
  let i, j;

  for(i in $scope.dataStorage1) {
    for (j in $scope.dataStorage2) {
      if ($scope.dataStorage1[i].caption.id === $scope.dataStorage2[j].caption.id) {
        $scope.commonDataStorage.push($scope.dataStorage1[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Вопрос в том, как написать код который будет проверять есть ли в массиве $scope.commonDataStorage добавляемый элемент и если нет, то добавлять в противном случае не добавлять элемент.

Comment: Метод arr.includes(a) возвращает true или false

Comment: @slowBro Спасибо за подсказку, метод работает, но похоже я неправильно его использую, буду разбираться, еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот это:

```
function getCommonData() {
  let i, j;
  for (i in $scope.dataStorage1) {
    if (this.isDuplicate($scope.dataStorage1[i].caption.id)) {
      $scope.commonDataStorage.push($scope.dataStorage1[i]);
    }
  }
  for (j in $scope.dataStorage2) {
    if (this.isDuplicate($scope.dataStorage2[j].caption.id)) {
      $scope.commonDataStorage.push($scope.dataStorage2[i]);
    }
  }
}

function isDuplicate(id) {
  const duplicatedItem = $scope.commonDataStorage.filter((item) => item.caption.id === id);
  return duplicatedItem.length === 0;
}
```